How to get Miller indexes from a diffraction pattern?
Working with a single crystal, what is the first thing the diffractometer has access to? What is the output I see and what are the steps from this two levels of information?
If I'm correct, the output might be (hkl) indices and their intensities, but I don't know how the instrument can assign the coordinates in reciprocal space to the spots.
Is necessary for it to know the orientation of the crystallographic axes respect to the goniometer?
How does it calculate it?
It's not tightly necessary a too much detailed answer, but I need an ensemble vision of the situation.
I post it also in Chemistry SE because maybe the field is quite superimposable.
